# Android - Exporting the Equalized Audio File

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

I'm currently using a modified version of [this Android Equalizer App](https://github.com/bullheadandplato/AndroidEqualizer) where I fetch an Audio File (A recording I made from a separate application) from the file system instead of the Assets folder. It currently works great, the app manages to open the Audio File and I'm able to boost and mute certain frequencies.

However, I also need to be able to "export" the "edited" audio file with the boosted and muted frequencies. The main challenge right now is that neither the `MediaPlayer` nor the `Equalizer` objects have methods that can export the audio they're playing. Another limitation is that `MediaRecorder` records form the microphone, which is a problem because it can introduce noise into the recording, or even record nothing at all if there's a headset connected.

I have read the [Playback Capture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture) but I don't think this will work on devices running Android OS earlier than Android Q (Android 10).

Now I'm genuinely stumped how to proceed.

My goal is this: Do a recording through the microphone, adjust certain frequencies in the audio file, and then save the edited audio file. If there's a much more efficient way of doing this, then I'm open to any ideas.

My main question is: Is there a way to "save" the audio file after "it's run through" the equalizer? I realize how oversimplified I put the entire scenario, and I acknowledge my general lack of knowledge about this subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

im also tryed to do this. i solve this with fmod.
for exaple:

> dsp->setParameterFloat(FMOD_DSP_THREE_EQ_LOWGAIN, 2);

> channel->addDSP(index, dsp);

or this:

> FMOD_DSP_MULTIBAND_EQ

And in fmod you can get many more settings than is in simple equalizer, also it can be saved with effects without any problems